# OpenGL 2D collision detection isn't working

Tags: java, opengl, 2d, collision-detection

I have a 2D OpenGL game which I am trying to implement aabb collision detection in.  Here is the collision detection code:

```
boolean collisionX = position.x + size.x + dx >= collision.position.x && collision.position.x + collision.size.x >= position.x + dx;
boolean collisionY = position.y + size.y + dy >= collision.position.y && collision.position.y + collision.size.y >= position.y + dy;
return collisionX && collisionY;
```

For the size I am using this calculation, because some of these sprite are from texture atlases.

```
size.x = pixelWidth * scaleX / modelTexture.spriteWidth,
size.y = pixelHeight * scaleY / modelTexture.spriteWidth
```

I use **modelTexture.spriteWidth** for both because the height and width of the texture atlas is the same, because it is a 2^x square.

**PixelWidth and PixelHeight** are the pixel size of the image on the texture, counted by me.

I think the problem could be because of these calculations, if they are wrong.  Please let me know.

However, the collision detection seems to be happening in the wrong places, as if the bounding box of every sprite begins in the center and extends towards the top right.  I have tried to account for this using a displacement vector which is equal to -size / 2f.  But unfortunately it didn't change anything.

Here is an example of a collision, which doesn't appear to be alligned correctly:

[image]

Do you think the problem could be the origin of the sprites/objects?  Which is at the center.  If so how would I set the origin to the top left?

Comment: Try one of the default methods, e.g. `boolean intersects = new Rectangle(x1, y1, width1, height1).intersects(new Rectangle(x2, y2, width2, height2));` from `java.awt` and see how that goes

Comment: If you need to scale the sizes, you'll probably have to scale the positions accordingly?

Comment: `position.x + size.x + dx >= collision.position.x && collision.position.x + collision.size.x >= position.x + dx;` shouldn't it be an `||` here ? (Same of y) Just an intuition reading the code, I haven't done the math

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino I'm not doing that because OpenGL world space is based on floats, and the awt Rectangle only does integers.  I suppose I could scale up the position and scale to make them whole numbers?  But I'm not sure how I would do that.  If you know let me know.

Comment: @RetoKoradi no because the position is already in world space, the reason I have to adjust the size is because it is calculated from the texture itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just validate collision against one side. To validate collisions you must do somethint like that:

```
collisionX = (right_side_Obj1 > left_side_Obj2 && left_side_Obj1 < left_side_Obj2) 
|| (left_side_Obj1 < right_side_Obj2 && right_side_Obj1 > right_side_Obj2);
```

In your case i think it should be:

```
boolean collisionX = (position.x + size.x + dx >= collision.position.x 
            && position.x <= collision.position.x)
        || (position.x - dx <= collision.position.x + collision.size.x
            && position.x + + size.x >= collision.position.x + collision.size.x);
```

Comment: I changed the method to what you posted, but it didn't help, the collisions still are not working.  And the boxes appear to be more messed up, its hard to tell though.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Two comparisons in each coordinate direction are enough to check for rectangle overlap. I find it easier to think about the conditions where they do *not* overlap, which is the case if the left of one is larger than the right of the other. This gives two conditions. Then you logically negate the expression, giving the two conditions for checking overlap.